# Не могу получить список скинов cs2 по определнному запросу в формате json

Tags: парсер, steam, steam-web-api

Сейчас получаю эти данные простым парсингом страницы. Мне необходимо сильно ускорить код, т.к. запросов очень много. Я выявил, что основную часть времени код тратит на получение списка скинов по определенному запросу. Есть ли возмодность ускорить этот процесс? Использовать json или xml? В интернете не нашел ответ на этот вопрос.